# Why isn't C++ inheritance in multiple header and source files working?

Tags: c++, inheritance, forward-declaration

So after some research I have been struggling to have separate class header and source code for my inheritance classes. The following examples are shortened versions of my classes. All of my headers have include guards, default constructors and virtual destructors. They also have getter and setter functions as needed for the variables. I will mainly just show the variables and the includes.

### THE COMPILER ERRORS ARE AT THE BOTTOM BELOW THE CODE

### MainProgram class:

**MainProgram.h**

```
#include "FileMgr.h"
#include "InfoMgr.h"

class FileMgr;
class InfoMgr;

class MainProgram
{
private:
    FileMgr* fileMgr;
    InfoMgr* infoMgr;
public:
             .
             .
             .
}; // !MainProgram
```

**MainProgram.cpp**

```
#include "MainProgram.h"
#include <iostream>
```

### MgrBase class (the base class):

**MgrBase.h**

```
#include "MainProgram.h"
#include <string>

class MainProgram;

class MgrBase
{
protected:
    MainProgram* mainProgram;

    MgrBase() : mainProgram(nullptr) {}
    virtual ~MgrBase() {}

public:
    virtual bool Init() = 0;
}; // !MgrBase
```

### FileMgr class:

**FileMgr.h**

```
#include "MgrBase.h"

class MainProgram;

class FileMgr : public MgrBase
{
public:
    FileMgr(MainProgram* mainProgram);
        .
        .
        .
};// !FileMgr
```

**FileMgr.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "FileMgr.h"
#include "MainProgram.h"
```

### InfoMgr class:

**InfoMgr.h**

```
#include <string>
#include "MgrBase.h"

class MainProgram;

class InfoMgr : public MgrBase
{
public:
    InfoMgr(MainProgram* mainProgram);
    .
    .
    .
}; //!InfoMgr
```

**InfoMgr.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MainProgram.h"
#include "InfoMgr.h"
```

## What I have tried and their errors:

So I have tried figuring out the class declarations and includes but I'm not getting it. With the way the code is now, I get this error on the '{' following class InfoMgr : public MgrBase:

```
 error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

If I make InfoMgr.h look like

```
#include <string>

//Class Foward Declarations
class MainProgram;
class MgrBase;
```

and InfoMgr.cpp look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MainProgram.h"
#include "InfoMgr.h"
#include "MgrBase.h"
```

I get this error in reference to the line class InfoMgr : public MgrBase

```
 error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class MgrBase’
```

If I make it so the InfoMgr.cpp doesn't include MgrBase and make it so InfoMgr.h looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include "MgrBase.h"

//Class Forward Declarations
class MainProgram;
class MgrBase;
```

I get this error in reference to the line class InfoMgr : public MgrBase

```
 error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class MgrBase’
```

Comment: Please create a [MCVE], preferably on some online compiler so that we can actually see the issue

Comment: What is meant by _not working_?

Comment: It's not compiling and giving me the errors at the end of the question.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I'm not sure what more you need, I really just left out the default constructors, the destructors and the class functions which are pretty much getters and setters right now.

Comment: We don't want "more"; we want a _minimal_ example, as explained in the Help Centre and behind the link Vittorio gave you. This is too much code; you haven't narrowed down the problem yet. Deconstructing a problem is a crucial skill in our line of work, so you'll be glad we made you learn it!

Comment: You also didn't say _where_ you get those errors, and your code files are incomplete.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have narrowed it down to the point in which I need help. I know that I am supposed to use forward class declarations in some way, but what I am doing is obviously wrong. So I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Well, construct a [MCVE] and if constructing one doesn't reveal to you what the problem is, then we can proceed.

Comment: Your `mainprogram.h` includes `infomgr.h`, which includes `mgrbase.h` which includes `mainprogram.h` which includes `infomgr.h` which includes.... This is kinda problematic, and i get it that you have guards set up, but in one of those headers you will always have problems with order.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I reduced the code enough to show where the classes were needed within the code. I know that to use the forward class declaration it is important to know what variables/pointers are being used.

Comment: It is not a [MCVE]. Please, click on the link and read the page. I'm not just being deliberately obtuse - you've gotta learn how to deconstruct a problem, and I'm trying to help you learn to write good SO questions so you can get better help in the future (and fewer downvotes, which will eventually lead to a question ban!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not being sarcastic, but I am really trying to figure out how to do that. I have made an edit, is it better now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a cycle in your header inclusion:

- `MainProgram.h` includes `FileMgr.h`
- `FileMgr.h` includes `MgrBase.h`
- `MgrBase.h` includes `MainProgram.h`

You need to break this cycle using forward declarations.

The rule in header files should be: if you only need to declare *reference* or *pointer* to a type `X`, forward declare `X` instead of including the header which defines it. The same applies if you're declaring (not defining) a function which has a parameter or return value of type `X`.

You only have to include the full definition of `X` if you're accessing members of `X` or defining a class derived from `X`.

In your case:

- Move both `#include` statements from `MainProgram.h` to `MainProgram.cpp`
- Remove `#include "MainProgram.h"` from `MgrBase.h`